# How to sync between PC and android by WiFi File Explorer PRO?

Tags: applications, sync

I bought the app because it says "In this PRO version, you can also upload, sync, delete, copy, and zip or unzip all the files on your Android phone and computer"

I can download, upload, but I don't know how to sync a folder.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B004OZOTSQ/ref=mas_ty](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004OZOTSQ)

Comment: Alternatives [Cheetah Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrtstudio.SyncFolders)  
[Wifi Syncr](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/wifi-syncr-sync-files-from-computer-to-android-device-over-wifi/)

Comment: Yeah, sure there are alternatives (my preference *for sync* still is [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/foldersync/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full), I'm quite happy with it). But the question was specifically about a "promised feature" of the app in the question (sorry, I don't know it either, as I never used that app).